# Moduli interpretation of normalization of moduli space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rigid-analytic-geometry, formal-schemes, normalization

The question is about formal and rigid geometry, but I would be interested in an answer from an algebraic geometry point of view as well.

Let $\mathfrak{X}$ be a formal moduli space (e.g., the formal completion of some moduli space $X$), and $\mathcal{X}$ its rigid fiber (both normal). Then let $\mathcal{X}^\prime \to \mathcal{X}$ be a finite map, where $\mathcal{X}^\prime$ has some moduli interpretation as well (it classifies the things that $\mathcal{X}$ classifies with some extra fixed bit of data). Let $\mathfrak{X}^\prime$ be the normalization of $\mathfrak{X}$ in $\mathcal{X}^\prime$. Does $\mathfrak{X}^\prime$ have a nice moduli interpretation related to that of $\mathcal{X}^\prime$?

For example, we could take $X$ to be the moduli space of elliptic curves with a chosen point of order $N \geq 5$, $X^\prime$ the moduli of elliptic curves with a chosen point of order $Np$ for some prime $p$, and $\mathcal{X}^\prime \to \mathcal{X}$ the rigid map corresponding to $X^\prime \to X$. I expect in this case that $\mathfrak{X}^\prime$ should just be the formal completion of $X^\prime$, and therefore should have some moduli interpretation, so the answer is yes. But in the case that $\mathcal{X}^\prime$ doesn't come directly from a scheme (or even that $\mathfrak{X}$ itself doesn't come directly from a scheme), this is not clear to me.

EDIT: Having thought more about this, I'm convinced it's a difficult question. It's easier to construct maps $\textit{out}$ of this normalization $\mathfrak{X}^\prime$, not into it, which makes it hard to describe its "points". (See the Stacks Project page https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BAK, Lemma 29.53.4 for the universal property of the relative normalization.) This also makes it difficult to describe the fibers of the map. Can we even say, for example, that the rigid fiber of $\mathfrak{X}^\prime$ is $\mathcal{X}^\prime$? This isn't clear to me, though I think there is at least a map between them.

Comment: I'm rather pessimistic about a general modular interpretation of the normalization.